# my itoa doesn't work with big numbers

Tags: c

I was given an assignment to implement `itoa`, my code doesn't work with `-2147483648`. How can I get this to work?

```
char    *itoa(int nbr)
{
    static char rep[] = "0123456789";
    static char buff[65];
    char        *ptr;
    int         neg;

    ptr = &buff[64];
    *ptr = '\0';
    neg = nbr;
    // fails here, turning -2147483648 to int
    //2147483648 is bigger than int.
    if (nbr < 0)
        nbr *= -1;
    if (nbr == 0)
        *--ptr = rep[nbr % 10];
    while (nbr != 0)
    {
        *--ptr = rep[nbr % 10];
        nbr /= 10;
    }
    if (neg < 0)
        *--ptr = '-';
    return (ptr);
}
```

Comment: learn about limits......

Comment: I cannot use `long`, my function prototype requires `nbr` to be `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to convert -2147483648 to 2147483648 with the following code

```
if (nbr < 0)
  nbr *= -1;
```

2147483648 does not fit in an `int` on your system. You might want to convert `nbr` to a type such as `long long` that can handle a bigger value before doing this operation.

```
long long my_positive = nbr;
if (my_positive < 0)
      my_positive*= -1;
```

Comment: Sorry, but how this helps to solve the issue? can you elaborate please?

Comment: The OP algo does not work when the input integer is -2147483648 because the algo attemps to converts it to 2147483648. `int` is not handling such value in OP system. C99 standard specifies that `long long` should be able to handle at least value up to 9223372036854775807. Using `long long` within the algo solve the issue OP is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

As your in-code comment says, the number is too big for an int to handle. Try using a long instead, it has a much larger range and should be able to store 2147483648.